# WebView height not changed after update the constraint constant

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios-autolayout

I am using webview inside the uicollectionview cell. I update the webview height constraint constant after the html was loaded. in following way.

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Load Completed")
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
            if complete != nil {
                self.webview.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.webviewHeightConstraint.constant = height as! CGFloat
                        print("Height ",height as! CGFloat)
                        self.webview.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

it give correct height value but ui is not changed until i scrolled little. But i start the scroll, webview height changed correctly. What is the issue here. Please help me.

Thank you,

Comment: You updated the constraints, but shouldn't the layoutSubViews by called for this change to take effect in the UI? I would suggest trying setNeedsLayout() and then layoutIfNeeded for your update to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
self.webview.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```

with

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: no, not working. i tried both like self.view.layoutIfNeeded() and self.webview.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to WKWebView

The full code for WKWebView would then be:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.scrollView.contentSize
}
```